# hide() not working immediately after show()

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I am currently working on a menu with dropdown functionality. The dropdown menu appears using **jQuery UI**'s "show('slide',...)" function on mouseenter and slides back using its "hide('slide',...) function.

The following is a code snippet I put together to demonstrate my problem, which occurs when very quickly moving the mouse over the  *Text*  element.

I have tried using .stop(true, true) and .dequeue() but with no success.
I got a feeling the problem lies on the **$(this).children()** call. Note that my usage of classes and children is deliberate, as it is unnecessary in this case, but needed in my project. With a streight *$(<#myElement>)* call it seems to work.

I am thankful for any constructive feedback on this. I've spent the entire day googleing/ trial and error/ troubleshooting this.

```js
   $(".element").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).children(".toggleme").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).children(".toggleme").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   });
```

```html
<div class="element"> 
   <span> TEST </span>
   <div class="toggleme" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: red; display: none;">
      I appear and vanish!
   </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, so forgive me if I am. What exactly is your problem? Do you not want the block to disappear when the mouse leaves?

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that while this effect works it is very easy to trip up and have the menu get "stuck" open.  I would suggest using CSS transitions for menus like this, you really don't need javascript for this.  Depending on how many objects or menus are on the screen this approach can get messy fast.

Comment: @RhapX: Yes, the block should simply disappear when the mouse leaves. Please note that this is a simplified version of my project. Which leads me to

Comment: @eyegropram: I need jQuery since in my project where this problem occurs I need to reset the element's position and such. CSS3 is not suitable for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off doing something like this:

```
// handle the mouse entering
jQuery(document).on('mouseover', ".element", function () {
    $(this).children(".toggleme").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
});
// handle the mouse leaving
jQuery(document).on('mouseout', ".element", function () {
    $(this).children(".toggleme").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
});
```

Instead of chaining it as you've done.

---

References

- [`jQuery.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
- [`jQuery.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Alternatively, you could also use [`jQUery.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) but the above should do as you require.

Comment: Seems to me that delegation is the right approach here to maintain a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your issue is with the red not hiding on mouseleave, wrap inside a $(document).ready();

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".element").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children(".toggleme").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
      }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children(".toggleme").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
      });
   });
```

You also need to import jQuery UI

http://plnkr.co/edit/qC1dWlTG7pu1QR4fW8h0?p=preview

Comment: ^ You are not importing jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would recommend the `slideToggle` method here. But since you want the animation from the left, seems that `animate` fits the bill.

```
$(".element").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children(".toggleme").animate({width: 'toggle'});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).children(".toggleme").animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oavxepoy/).

Comment: While this does work, and I know using "animate" the "stop" function also works, it doesn't tell me why my approach isn't successful.

Comment: Also using the animate function how can i achieve the "right to left" slide in animation?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```js
   $(".element").children("span").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).siblings(".toggleme").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   });
   $(".element").children("div").mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   });
```

```html
<div class="element"> 
   <span> TEST </span>
   <div class="toggleme" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: red; display: none;">
      I appear and vanish!
   </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works and behaves as desired, but you've changed the html in a way that I cannot do in my project. Now in your jQuery change the mouseleave function to "$('.element').mouseleave..." and in its body do "$(this).siblings('.togglename')...".
Now the mouseenter function works analogue to the mouseleave function -> only with the original problem. And my question is why?

Comment: See edit with no change to HTML. You are working your hover based on the "element" div. You need to target the span inside the "element" div. If you target the "element" div for your hover, it won't hide and show as you expect because the "element" div is a larger area. I'm not 100% sure if I fully understand though so maybe I'm way off!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".element").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).children(".toggleme").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).children(".toggleme").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 100);
   });
```

```css
.element {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"> 
   <span> TEST </span>
   <div class="toggleme" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: red; display: none;">
      I appear and vanish!
   </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This works as expected, because `.element` is a block element, so it takes up 100% of the width of the page. Even though you *think* your are not hovering the element anymore, you are still on it with your cursor. A solution is to set `.element` to `display: inline-block;`.